# What line-endings may I expect in multiline f-strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on Windows and have Python 3.9. In my script I am construcing a string as f-string with multiple lines:

```
XY="multiline"
MY_F_STRING = f'''my
{XY}
f-string
ends
here.'''
```

Even though my editor tells mit that the line endings in the file are dos style (\r\n) *and* looking at the bytes on disc I see the corresponding hex codes for CRLF, the repr of MY_F_STRING tells me that line endings are unix style (\n).

My Question is: Is this to-be-expected behavior? What is the general rule about this?

Comment: "which line endings"?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Are you asking about new-line characters like `\n`?

Comment: Print the `repr()` of the value of the f-string and see for yourself.

Comment: According to Wikipedia the term "line endings" cannot be misunderstood 

Comment: Can you please explain why this is an issue?  I ask because Python scripts are platform portable (in most cases), so the interpreter will compensate for the OS’ line endings in the background.

Comment: Python reads its source files in "Universal newline" text mode, translating all common new lines formats to simply `\n`.  If you want specific newlines in your f-string, use escape codes, e.g. `s = f'my\nf-string\r\nhas\rdifferent newlines'`.

Comment: Ref. [PEP 278](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/).  Universal newlines allows Python scripts written on different OSes to work seemlessly and consistently on other OSes.  Would you want your string constant to change content when run on Linux vs. Windows?

Comment: Hello @MarkTolonen. Thanks for that information! (I had expected to make my script aware of platform and react accordingly. But this way is better I guess!) Python N00b over and out ;-)

Comment: @MarkTolonen the question was re-opened and may accept answers. Would you want to to put your comments in an answer so that i can accept it? I am still convinced that this is a good question and that it may help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python reads its source files in "Universal newline" text mode, translating all common new lines formats to simply `\n`. If you want specific newlines in your f-string, use escape codes, e.g. `s = f'my\nf-string\r\nhas\rdifferent newlines'`.

Refer also to [PEP 278](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/). Universal newlines allows Python scripts written on different OSes to work seemlessly and consistently on other OSes. Would you want your string constant to change content when run on Linux vs. Windows?